# sample from randomly generated numbers?

Tags: python, numpy, random

There is a program that needs to get 100 samples from 1000 randomly generated number distributed in `[1, 500]`. How can do I get a random sample from the output?

I wrote the following:

```
N = 1000
x = 1 + 500 * np.random.rand(N) 
sp_x = random.sample(x, 100)
```

I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code, the resulting `x` is a numpy array.
To check `type(x)` output: `numpy.ndarray`

But the function `random.sample(sequence, k)` can only take in a sequence that is a `list`, `tuple`, `string`, or `set`. So your code could be:

```
import random
N = 1000
x = 1 + 500*np.random.rand(N) 
x = list(x)
sp_x = random.sample(x, 100)
print(len(sp_x))
```

output: `100`

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `random.sample` is misidentifying the sequence.  You can easily fix this by forcing a conversion of the input to a `list` type.

```
sp_x = random.sample(list(x), 100)
```

This is why [EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/5987) is such an important principle in Python - if `random.sample` had simply tried to iterate on the input, it would have succeeded.  Instead it checked the type and failed when it wasn't an expected iterable type.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) module, and in particular [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), is not really intended to work with numpy. Since you're using arrays, stick with numpy routines since they are generally much more efficient.

To generate the first array more simply, use [`np.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
x = np.random.uniform(1, 500, size=N)
```

You can sample the 100 items in a number of ways in numpy. A very basic method is to apply [`np.random.shuffle`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) to `x` and slice off the first 100 elements:

```
np.random.shuffle(x)
sp_x = x[:100]
```

Another option is to use[`np.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
sp_x = np.random.choice(x, 100, replace=False)
```

All of the above is using the legacy API. The new [`Generator` API](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start) is preferred and generally much more efficient.

```
gen = np.random.default_rng()
x = gen.uniform(1, 500, size=N)
sp_x = gen.choice(x, 100, replace=False)
```

Keep in mind that using [`np.random.rand`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.rand.html), [`random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) and [`random.Generator.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html) selects floating point values on the interval `[1, 500)`. If you wanted to generate integers in `[1, 500]` instead, do something like

```
x = np.random.randint(1, 501, size=N)
```

Or

```
x = gen.integers(500, endpoint=True, size=N)
```